# dnsmasq statistics not match cache-size in dnsmasq.conf

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

When i use command "kill -s SIGUSR1 `cat /var/run/dnsmasq.pid`", the output in log is as below:

```
Dec  2 14:23:48 dnsmasq[22548]: cache size 10000, 22230/42649 cache insertions re-used unexpired cache entries.
Dec  2 14:23:48 dnsmasq[22548]: queries forwarded 97058, queries answered locally 544818
```

I am so confused that the cache size is 10000, but "the total number of names that have been inserted into the cache" is 42649, why these two numbers are not the same? And how can i make cache size bigger than 10000 if my memory is lager enough?

Comment: Well, your cache has a maximum of 10000 items, but over a period of time 42649 insertions were performed on it. As DNS caches feature expiration control, some of these insertions went into "free slots" of previously expired items and 22230 simply overwrote unexpired items (probably b/c the cache was full). Does that make any sense?

Comment: sorry i have no idea what is "free slots",i want to increase cache size that make more domain can be cache. how can i do that?

Comment: The hard limit seems to be 10000, no way to increase above that. Free slots: as cache items expire, the space they occupy in the cache gets released, those are free slots.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 22230 means： there are 22230 items had been cached. But at the same time dnsmasq can cached only 10000 domains? Am I right?

Comment: Ok, let's assume for a second you run a restaurant with a total capacity of catering for 100 guests at once. _Over a day_, you can easy have 500 guests, because guests come, eat and go. This is the same with the cache, but you have a capacity of 10000 guests at once, with 42649 total guests served over the period reported.  Your restaurant is also *super* busy, so over the reported period, you had to ask 22230 guests (probably those who already had their meal and now just waste precious space with idle chatting at the table) to leave and make room for new paying guests. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

After cloning the repo

```
git clone git://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq.git
```

and looking at the source file **dnsmasq/src/cache.c** that produces the log messages, 10000 is the integer struct element **daemon->cachesize**. This value has already been explained in the comments, it is the maximum number of DNS cache entries allowed, not a particular measure of memory.

The value 22230 is the variable **cache_live_freed**, 42649 is the variable **cache_inserted**, and both start at zero and both are reset to zero on a cache reload.

Variable **cache_inserted** increments on any successful commit of an entry to the cache, whether the inserting is new, or replacing something that expired. There is also such a thing as an unsuccessful or incomplete commit, which doesn't get counted by this variable.

Variable **cache_live_freed** has a rather complex meaning, but basically gets down to replacing an expired cache entry.